# Excel ListObject Update When Source Changes

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, listobject

I have an Excel worksheet with a ListObject on it. I currently have this bound to a List but when I update an element in the List, the ListObject does not refresh unless I call RefreshDataRow.

I have tried using a BindingSource and setting the datasource of the BindingSource to my list but this still does not reflect changes to the ListObject.

Is there a method by which I can bind a collection to a ListObject and have it update on-screen when I change an element in the underlying collection in code (without calling RefreshDataRow).

Regards
Alan

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ttzcbhb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), where it says:

> The ListObject is updated automatically when it is bound to a data
>   source, such as a DataTable, that raises events when the data changes.
>   If you bind the ListObject to a data source that does not raise events
>   when the data changes, you must call the RefreshDataRow or
>   RefreshDataRows method to update the ListObject.

so probably you should provide a source meeting those requirements.